# Exporting Access data that includes calculated fields into an Excel worksheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2012, ms-access-2010

I am doing a programming project for my visual basic class, we are using Visual Studios 2012. What I would like to know, if at all possible is if there is a way to export an Access table into an Excel file (by pressing a menu item in the form) that I can then put the name of the file as the time and date the file was created.

Right now, I have one form, with a menu-strip, where I placed the option to export to Excel.

The program has the user enter items that they are sending to and receiving from a laundry with quantities. I have got the moving of data from the form to the Access table finished, but I need to be able to create an excel file with that data from that table in it with the day and time as the file name. I am not using VBA, and I think it may be too late to start using VBA at this stage in the project. I am using the techniques from a series of videos I found on YouTube, here is the link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07ioTflBrHQ

I am completely stuck on this, and all the solutions I look for are in VBA, but I need whatever Visual Studios 2012 is using. Any help offered will greatly appreciated, and if VBA is required, I would ask that you would treat me as a beginner with any explanations or code you may have, because I am a beginner to visual basic, and I have no idea how VBA works.

Edit:

The technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230015/export-access-query-to-excel-in-console-application) looks promising, but one of the fields I want to export is a `Calculated` field and it triggers the error

> Calculated columns are not allowed in SELECT INTO statements.

Perhaps there is a workaround for this?

Comment: It's definitely not VB6. VB6 is ancient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export access query to excel in console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230015/export-access-query-to-excel-in-console-application)

Comment: Well, this is one of those times that I love the internet. Thank you Gord Thompson. It worked, Now I just need to modify it for the details. One last question: I have a calculated field that I also want to export, but I get the message "calculated fields are not allowed in SELECT INTO statements." Any ideas? And once again, thank you, you saved me a lot of stress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Access does not allow Calculated Fields to be included in SELECT INTO statements. For a table named [SampleData]

```
SampleID  Prefix  FirstName  LastName  FullName        
--------  ------  ---------  --------  ----------------
       1  Mr      Gord       Thompson  Mr Gord Thompson
       2  Miss    Anne       Elk       Miss Anne Elk
```

where [FullName] is a Calculated Field, if we try

```csharp
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText =
            @"SELECT SampleID, FullName " +
            @"INTO [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\__tmp\zzzNew.xls].[Sheet1] " +
            @"FROM SampleData";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

we get the error

> Calculated columns are not allowed in SELECT INTO statements.

However, we can fool Access into doing our bidding by using the calculated field in an *expression* for one of the output columns:

```csharp
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = 
            @"SELECT SampleID, '' & FullName AS FullName " +
            @"INTO [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\__tmp\zzzNew.xls].[Sheet1] " +
            @"FROM SampleData";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

(This is C# code, but the VB.NET code would be very similar.)

**Edit re: comment**

To create an Excel document in the newer `.xlsx` format, use this

```csharp
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = 
            @"SELECT SampleID, '' & FullName AS FullName " +
            @"INTO [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\__tmp\zzzNew.xlsx].[Sheet1] " +
            @"FROM SampleData";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Gord, I got it to work. I was wondering, is this possible to do with an ".xlsx" file extension for an Excel 2010 0r 2013 file? I tried and the file was made, but I couldn't open the .xlsx file because the extension "wasn't Valid" I believe it's because of the part of the code that says "Excel 8.0;" I would have to change that to 14.0 or 15.0 depending on the version of Excel I would want to use correct? When I change it to 14.0 I get an unhandled exception error. It's not super important to do that part, but I was just wondering if it could be done.